# trying to do UML diagramming with papyrus on eclipse but no diagrams are shown...what could be the issue?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, papyrus

I have eclipse 4.2 and papyrus 0.9. I have started modelling a project by creating class Diagrams but the issue is that papyrus does not draw the diagrams on the editor pane. I can create and add attributes and operations from the model explorer and i can view them from there but i can't see any diagrams on the editor. i do use the papyrus perspective when modelling. so my question is.

1. what am i doing wrong?
2. do i need to add other papyrus components?
3. or is this how papyrus works?

but from the pdf tutorials from the eclipse papyrus project site shows diagrams being drawn with a palette view that i can't seem to find in my eclipse..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Eclipse Kepler (4.3) and Papyrus (4.3), I was unable to find a way to update the view (class diagram) from the model (model explorer.)  If I created the operation by dragging an operation node from the palette to the class in the view, the operation was added to both the diagram and model explorer.

You need to switch to the Papyrus perspective in order for palette view to show up.

I just blogged about [this and a few other annoyances](http://www.selikoff.net/2013/06/30/creating-a-uml-diagram-with-eclipse-papyrus/).  (I realize this question is old enough that you've likely given up, but I found it while searching for a solution to this same problem.)